# Can a stable vinylic carbocation be formed?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

Is it possible to prepare/form a vinylic primary carbocation? Will it be stable (low energy) or not?

Comment: Related: [Why are vinylic and arylic carbocations highly unstable?](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10509)

Comment: Would you like to know the reactions which consist of vinylic carbocation intermediates? Please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: @Abcd Yes i would love to, it will help a lot. Thank you for support.

Comment: What does this question mean? Low energy? Compared to what?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1010603016311649 Yes, you can make such things.

Comment: @Zhe Oh thats a good one article. Is there any evidence for a **non aromatic** vinyl carbocation ?

Comment: In general yes, google vinyl iodonium salts, a primary one though is unlikely

Comment: See references at bottom. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinyl_cation